# List of Azure SQL databases - usage by server using REST API

Tags: c#, azure, rest, azure-sql-database

I can get a database usage report (including DB actual and maximum size) for a single database using REST API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/2021-05-01-preview/database-usages/list-by-database?tabs=HTTP

I want to get the same database usage report by server name for all the databases on that server. Is it possible using the Azure REST API?

Answer (score 1):

You can list of all databases contained on that Azure SQL logical server using [this REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/2021-05-01-preview/databases/list-by-server?tabs=HTTP).

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444/resourceGroups/Default-SQL-SouthEastAsia/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/testsvr/databases?api-version=2021-05-01-preview
```

You can then iterate through the list returned and get the database usage for each database using the REST API you referenced in your question.

Comment: Thanks, Alberto. It returns maxSizeBytes of each database, I was looking for the actual size. I could achieve the same using the SQL query but would be nice if I could get it using restapi. Qry - Select * from
(
select
       @@serverName as ServerName,
    db.name as DatabaseName,
       (select top 1 s.storage_in_megabytes from sys.resource_stats s where s.database_name = db.name order by s.start_time desc) as DatabaseMB
from
       sys.databases db
)t
order by DatabaseMB desc

Comment: Use the following endpoint: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions//resourceGroups//providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers//databases//usages?api-version=2014-04-01-preview The result is a json that looks like the following: name : database_size resourceName : displayName : Database Size currentValue : 2324692992.0 limit : 268435456000.0 unit : Bytes nextResetTime :